# How disable keyboard in a webView browser (JavaFx)?

Tags: browser, webview, javafx, keyboard

I would disable the keyboard when i show a webView browser in a scene with JavaFx, for example when I open Google with that browser i want you not be able to type in search field. How can i disable keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable **all** user input (keyboard, mouse, etc) to the `WebView`, you can call

```
webView.setDisable(true);
```

If you only want to block keyboard input (so you allow mouse input, etc), add an event filter that consumes keyboard events:

```
webView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, KeyEvent::consume);
```

Note that this doesn't prevent the user from (for example) searching on google as they can use the mouse to paste text into text fields, etc.